# Merge 2 lists of lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I´m looking to merge 2 lists of lists. In the first piece of code I can merge 2 lists of strings without the repeated elements! That is what I´m looking for but with 2 lists of lists (of strings):

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
list2 = ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
# List merge without dupe
list1.extend([element for element in list2 if element not in list1])
print list1
>>>
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

What I´m looking for:

```
list1=[["artur","1/1/2018","0.5"],
       ["paco","1/1/2018","2.11"],
       ["pepe","1/1/2018","11.2"],
       ["artur","2/1/2018","0.5"],
       ["paco","2/1/2018","2.11"],
       ["pepe","2/1/2018","11.2"]]

list2=[["artur","1/1/2018","Estable"],
       ["paco","1/1/2018","Critico"],
       ["pepe","1/1/2018","Critico"], 
       ["artur","2/1/2018","Estable"],
       ["paco","2/1/2018","Critico"],
       ["pepe","2/1/2018","Critico"]]

#desired output:
>>>list1
[["artur","1/1/2018","0.5","Estable"],
 ["paco","1/1/2018","2.11","Critico"],
 ["pepe","1/1/2018","11.2","Critico"],
 ["artur","2/1/2018","0.5","Estable"],
 ["paco","2/1/2018","2.11","Critico"],
 ["pepe","2/1/2018","11.2","Critico"]]
```

EDITION:

if my list will be:

```
list1=[["artur,1/1/2018,0.5"],
       ["paco,1/1/2018,2.11"],
       ["pepe,1/1/2018,11.2"],
       ["artur,2/1/2018,0.5"],
       ["paco,2/1/2018,2.11"],
       ["pepe,2/1/2018,11.2"]]

list2=[["artur,1/1/2018,Estable"],
       ["paco,1/1/2018,Critico"],
       ["pepe,1/1/2018,Critico"], 
       ["artur,2/1/2018,Estable"],
       ["paco,2/1/2018,Critico"],
       ["pepe,2/1/2018,Critico"]]
```

I had to convert a csv to list but I have this kind of list and not what I´m asked in the fist lines of the question!

Comment: `[s1 + s2[2:] for s1, s2 in zip(list1, list2)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nested for loop that checks the first 2 element of each sub-list and appends when a match is found should work:

```
for sub1 in list1:
    for sub2 in list2:
        if sub1[:2] == sub2[:2]:
            sub1.append(sub2[-1])
            continue
```

Output:

```
>>>list1
[['artur', '1/1/2018', '0.5', 'Estable'],
 ['paco', '1/1/2018', '2.11', 'Critico'],
 ['pepe', '1/1/2018', '11.2', 'Critico'],
 ['artur', '2/1/2018', '0.5', 'Estable'],
 ['paco', '2/1/2018', '2.11', 'Critico'],
 ['pepe', '2/1/2018', '11.2', 'Critico']]
```

Comment: Thanks! That exactly what I´m looking for!

Comment: I just add some question in the ask! Could you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a `for` loop using `enumerate()`:

```
list1=[["artur","1/1/2018","0.5"],
       ["paco","1/1/2018","2.11"],
       ["pepe","1/1/2018","11.2"],
       ["artur","2/1/2018","0.5"],
       ["paco","2/1/2018","2.11"],
       ["pepe","2/1/2018","11.2"]]

list2=[["artur","1/1/2018","Estable"],
       ["paco","1/1/2018","Critico"],
       ["pepe","1/1/2018","Critico"], 
       ["artur","2/1/2018","Estable"],
       ["paco","2/1/2018","Critico"],
       ["pepe","2/1/2018","Critico"]]


for i, item in enumerate(list2):
    list1[i].append(item[-1])

>>> pprint(list1)
[['artur', '1/1/2018', '0.5', 'Estable'],
 ['paco', '1/1/2018', '2.11', 'Critico'],
 ['pepe', '1/1/2018', '11.2', 'Critico'],
 ['artur', '2/1/2018', '0.5', 'Estable'],
 ['paco', '2/1/2018', '2.11', 'Critico'],
 ['pepe', '2/1/2018', '11.2', 'Critico']]
```

**Edit**:

```
list1=[["artur,1/1/2018,0.5"],
       ["paco,1/1/2018,2.11"],
       ["pepe,1/1/2018,11.2"],
       ["artur,2/1/2018,0.5"],
       ["paco,2/1/2018,2.11"],
       ["pepe,2/1/2018,11.2"]]

list2=[["artur,1/1/2018,Estable"],
       ["paco,1/1/2018,Critico"],
       ["pepe,1/1/2018,Critico"], 
       ["artur,2/1/2018,Estable"],
       ["paco,2/1/2018,Critico"],
       ["pepe,2/1/2018,Critico"]]

# slice assignment
list1[:] = [''.join(item).split(',') for item in list1]
list2[:] = [''.join(item).split(',') for item in list2]

for i, item in enumerate(list2):
    list1[i].append(item[-1])

>>> pprint(list1)
[['artur', '1/1/2018', '0.5', 'Estable'],
 ['paco', '1/1/2018', '2.11', 'Critico'],
 ['pepe', '1/1/2018', '11.2', 'Critico'],
 ['artur', '2/1/2018', '0.5', 'Estable'],
 ['paco', '2/1/2018', '2.11', 'Critico'],
 ['pepe', '2/1/2018', '11.2', 'Critico']]
```

Comment: Please, try to do it with this CSV Files because I can do it with your code: 
List1: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tt6vW21ky3iHQTRHclSSTEsWjqbfIC_Y/view?usp=sharing
List2: 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=11qyUr0Gew8r4HBPlH86p_pWbUfK1wv_J

Comment: I tried with `list1[:] = [', '.join(item).split(',') for item in list1]`

Comment: Please post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ziplist = list(zip(list1, list2))
outlist = []
for z in ziplist:
    for i in z[1]:
        if i not in z[0]:
            z[0].append(i)
    outlist.append(z[0])

print(outlist)
```

Output:

```
[['artur', '1/1/2018', '0.5', 'Estable'], 
 ['paco', '1/1/2018', '2.11', 'Critico'], 
 ['pepe', '1/1/2018', '11.2', 'Critico'], 
 ['artur', '2/1/2018', '0.5', 'Estable'], 
 ['paco', '2/1/2018', '2.11', 'Critico'], 
 ['pepe', '2/1/2018', '11.2', 'Critico']]
```